# Python: Get a list of attributes used by a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

I'd like a (Python 3.7+) function that, given a (class, method) pair, would give me a list of attributes that are needed to carry out the method's computation.

I am aware that the general case might be hard (or even impossible) to solve, so I'll make do with something that covers most cases (and would be happy if the cases that can't be safely handled could be detected (and the user warned about it)).

Consider the following:

```py
def func(obj):
    return obj.a + obj.b

class A:
    e = 2
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0, c=1, d=10):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def target_method(self, x=3):
        t = func(self)
        tt = self.other_method(t)
        return x * tt / self.e

    def other_method(self, x=1):
        return self.c * x
```

My desired `attr_used_by_method` function would do something like:

```py
>>> attr_used_by_method(cls=A, method_name='target_method')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

Because: `a` and `b` are used when the object is passed to `func`, `c` is used by the `other_method` method, and `self.e` is used to compute the return value. But the attribute `d` isn't necessary to computer `target_method` so is not returned.

I searched through `inspect` and `trace` packages to see if they could get the job done, but it looks like only `ast` will be able to get things done properly.

Any `ast` nerds out there?

For context: The reason I want such a function is to be able to create a "specialized json-serialization" that would only serialize those attributes that are needed to carry out a specific method of the object.

Comment: Does this need to be done statistically? I.e. you want to scan source code to do this? Or can you run the code? Also `self.e` is invalid syntax because `e` is a class variable (not part of `self`)

Comment: `self.e` will be found in the class, it is not an error.

Comment: Statically, you can check `A.target_method.__code__.co_names` and then recurse for methods it calls indirectly (although maybe use `dis` or `ast`). Dynamically, you can pass a proxy object instead of `self` and use `__getattribute__` to record what attributes are used on the branches that are taken.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, static would be more convenient since there'd be no need to figure out what kind of inputs are valid to run the method.

Comment: @o11c, +1 for the interesting idea for the dynamical case. I'd need to see how your static approach would work in practice. For the simple example mentioned above, it works, since all statements of the `target_method` involve `self`, but in general, the recursion would have to be filtered to only explore when functions involve the object or class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class Tracker:
    """
    Tracks the attribute access right after `start_track` is set to True.

    Add this to __metaclass__ for any class that you need to track attributes for given a
    target method.
    """
    attrs_to_ignore = []
    attr_used = []
    start_track = False

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        """
        Inspect getter for tracking the attributes accessed.
        """
        if item not in ['on_access']:
            self.on_access(item)
        return super().__getattribute__(item)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        """
        Inspect setter for tracking the attributes accessed.
        """
        if self.start_track:
            self.on_access(key)

        super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def on_access(self, key):
        """
        on attribute access, record attribute if and only if its not from
        core attribute or `attrs_to_ignore` set to class.
        """
        if key in ['start_track', 'attr_used', 'on_access', 'attrs_to_ignore'] or key in self.attrs_to_ignore:
            return
        if self.start_track:
            self.attr_used.append(key)


def attr_used_by_method(cls, method_name, method_params):
    """
    Tracks the access to attributes within an execution.
    """
    # create meta class with the above tracker and `cls` from parameters.
    tracker = type('Tracker', (Tracker, cls), dict(cls.__dict__, **Tracker.__dict__))()
    tracker.attrs_to_ignore = [func for func in dir(tracker) if callable(getattr(tracker, func))]
    if hasattr(tracker, method_name):
        candidate_method = getattr(tracker, method_name)
        # Now, we want to track attributes.
        tracker.start_track = True
        candidate_method(**method_params)
        attr_used = tracker.attr_used.copy()
        tracker.attr_used = []
        return attr_used
    else:
        # Error class/obj do not have that method.
        return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of variables which are being used by other functions and store them in a list and return that list by your named function "attr_used_by_method"

Answer (score 0):

The [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) can do. If we assume the source is stored in a variable named `source` (could be read from a file):

```
import ast

root = ast.parse(source)
names = sorted({node.id for node in ast.walk(root) if isinstance(node, ast.Name)})
```

That loses ordering to gain uniquification and friendly display order, but you could just use a list comprehension or generator expression instead of a set comprehension if you don't need uniqueness but want ordering. The resulting `list` is:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'do_something', 'f', 'myList', 'range', 'someMethod', 'something', 'x']
```

Comment: when applied to my example above, your code gives me `['func', 'self', 't', 'tt', 'x']`. The desired list should be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']`, the list of attributes that are needed to compute the `A.target_method`.